# Разработка мобильного меню для сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте!

Делаю меню для сайта (при маленьком разрешении)

Ссылка на сайт: [Клик](http://tvarinskydesign.16mb.com/)

Кажется, что-то получилось, столкнулся с такой проблемой, как незнающий человек спрашиваю у Вас - Как сделать чтобы меню в открытом состоянии скроллилось, а контент сайта нет?

Сейчас меню стоит на месте, а контент на фоне сайта листается, из-за fixed скорее всего.

Прикрепляю всю разметку связанную с меню

```js
var main = function() {

  $('#menumobile').click(function() {

    $('.swipemenu').animate({

      left: '0px'

    }, 200);

    $('.menuoverlay').animate({
      opacity: 0.8
    }, 300);
    $('.menuoverlay').show();


  });



  $('#close').click(function() {

    $('.swipemenu').animate({

      left: '-500'

    }, 200);

    $('.menuoverlay').animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 300);

    $('.menuoverlay').hide();
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-list").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('href'),

      top = $(id).offset().top;

    $('.swipemenu').animate({

      left: '-500'

    }, 200);

    $('.menuoverlay').animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 300);

    $('.menuoverlay').hide();

    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```css
.swipemenu {
  width: 80%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 4%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: -400px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
  transition: left 0.3s;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.imgonmenu {
  margin-left: 27.5%;
  margin-top: 8%;
  position: relative;
}

p.menutitle {
  font-family: 'oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #404040;
}

p.subtitlemenu {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 16%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #404040;
}

.menu-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.menu-list>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-list>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  left: 7.5%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s;
}

.menu-list>li>a i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.menu-list>li>a img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.iconsmargin {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #404040;
}

a.menulinks {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.375em;
  position: relative;
  color: #303030;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p.menutag {
  font-family: 'oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
  color: #808080;
  display: inline;
}

div.offset {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 7.5%;
}

div.lineonmenu {
  height: 1px;
  width: 95%;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 10%;
  position: relative;
  background: #b8b8b8;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.menuoverlay {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js"></script>

<div class="swipemenu">
  <a class="closemenu" id="close">X</a>
  <img src="img/modal/1.png" class="imgonmenu">
  <p class="menutitle">Ivan Tvarinsky</p>
  <p class="subtitlemenu">Front-end dev. | UI/UX Design</p>


  <div class="offset">
    <p class="menutag">MENU</p>
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
      <li><a href="#home" class="menulinks"><i class="fa fa-home iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
      <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
      <li><a href="#about" class="menulinks"><i class="fa fa-address-card iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i> About me</a></li>
      <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
      <li><a href="#portfolio" class="menulinks"><i class="fa fa-briefcase iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
      <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
      <li><a href="#comments" class="menulinks"><i class="fa fa-comments-o iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Comments</a></li>
      <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="menulinks"><i class="fa fa-envelope iconsmargin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact Info</a></li>
      <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="offset">
    <p class="menutag">CATEGORIES</p>
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
      <li>
        <a href="#1" class="menulinks"><img src="img/menu/1.png" class="imgicon" alt=""> Home</a>
      </li>
      <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
      <li>
        <a href="#2" class="menulinks"><img src="img/menu/2.png" class="imgicon" alt=""> About me</a>
      </li>
      <div class="lineonmenu"></div>
      <li>
        <a href="#3" class="menulinks"><img src="img/menu/3.png" class="imgicon" alt=""> Portfolio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="menuoverlay"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решил это я:

```
var main = function() {

    $('#menumobile').click(function() {

        $('.swipemenu').animate({

            left: '0px'

        }, 200);

        $('.menuoverlay').animate({ opacity: 0.7 }, 300);
        $('.menuoverlay').show();
        $('.swipemenu').css({"position" : "absolute"});
        $('.content').css({"position" : "fixed"});
        $('.footer').css({"display" : "none"});
        $('.container').css({"position" : "fixed"});
    });



    $('#close').click(function() {

        $('.swipemenu').animate({

            left: '-500'

        }, 200);

        $('.content').css({"position" : "inherit"});
        $('.footer').css({"display" : "block"});
        $('.container').css({"position" : "inherit"});
        $('.swipemenu').css({"position" : "fixed"});
        $('.menuoverlay').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300);
        $('.menuoverlay').hide();

    });
};

$(document).ready(main);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-list").on("click","a", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var id = $(this).attr('href'),

  top = $(id).offset().top;

        $('.swipemenu').animate({

            left: '-500'

        }, 200);

        $('.content').css({"position" : "inherit"});
        $('.footer').css({"display" : "block"});
        $('.container').css({"position" : "inherit"});
        $('.swipemenu').css({"position" : "fixed"});
        $('.menuoverlay').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300);
        $('.menuoverlay').hide();

  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Оформлять код JS/HTML/CSS нужно через фрагмент кода.

Comment: @Alex78191 переделал...

Comment: не понимаю зачем тут js. Щас покажу пример реализации на чистом css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Это маленький пример и не совпадает с вашей вёрсткой но принцип тот что нужен

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("");
        $(".menu").toggleClass("open");
    });
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  background: linear-gradient(#ccc, #fff, #ccc);
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -22%;
  transition: .5s;
}

.menu:hover {
  left: 0;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 1px 0;
}

.menu a {
  font-family: 'Keania One', cursive;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

.post a {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
  color: #fefefe;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.content {
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 30px;
}

.post {
  padding: 30px 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.post-header {
  font-size: 30px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #777;
  color: #dfdfdf;
}

button.hidden {
  position: fixed;
  background: darkred;
}

.menu.open {
  left: 0;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Subrayada" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Keania+One" rel="stylesheet">
<main>
  <button>Кнопка</button>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">item 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #1</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #2</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #3</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #4</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #5</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #6</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #7</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #8</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #9</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="post-header">
        <a href="">Post name #10</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Больше не актуально, но этот способ возьму на заметку, спасибо :)

Comment: быстро что то вы  решили

Comment: Прикрепил свой способ решения

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(".leftmenu").toggleClass("open");
    $(".content").toggleClass("block");
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.leftmenu_wrapper {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content.block {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.leftmenu {
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.leftmenu.open {
  display: block;
}

.leftmenu.open~.button {
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.button {
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .leftmenu {
    display: block;
  }
 .button {
  margin-left: 30%;
 }
  .content {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum error, doloremque repellat et unde beatae maxime, quae nesciunt natus repudiandae suscipit reprehenderit laboriosam amet quisquam sapiente, harum ullam veritatis quaerat excepturi perferendis
    voluptates! Inventore cupiditate, reprehenderit provident praesentium voluptates illum quis nobis quos aliquam eum molestiae, reiciendis enim nostrum iusto minima sed accusamus qui nam suscipit ipsam omnis. Accusamus sapiente autem quidem voluptatum
    cupiditate eos vero voluptates ab natus beatae architecto ea nobis voluptatibus omnis sunt ullam ut alias, voluptas ratione rem asperiores eum. Eius voluptas officia incidunt itaque, repellendus quasi animi illo mollitia in labore, rerum? Reiciendis
    illum voluptatem quo, atque dignissimos. Nostrum rem dicta esse, nulla iusto sunt omnis reiciendis qui, quo repellat suscipit odio, ipsum laboriosam ut ipsa incidunt veritatis quasi nobis tenetur sed excepturi. Architecto quae repellat veniam obcaecati
    est inventore libero nisi ex, illum vitae, ratione earum quod perspiciatis enim. Omnis, aliquid, accusantium. Inventore voluptate obcaecati vitae iste, rerum nihil corrupti recusandae sunt rem voluptas? Minus, ipsum. Consequuntur fugiat sit alias
    consectetur sed laborum, minima, tempore quibusdam cupiditate labore qui voluptatum maxime itaque et autem inventore? At ut quidem mollitia ipsam modi praesentium quae cumque deleniti nam quod quisquam, magnam rem asperiores delectus labore tempore,
    beatae dolorem vero impedit eaque officia aliquam enim harum, distinctio! Sequi quas in veritatis praesentium ad, cupiditate nobis eaque magni architecto assumenda, atque quisquam placeat tenetur aliquid asperiores minima, nihil voluptatum et provident
    dolores incidunt. Consectetur hic atque animi iure unde id facilis et doloribus suscipit inventore illo at in repudiandae dignissimos, dolorem numquam impedit temporibus, sequi iste labore dolores? Suscipit ut fugiat quaerat dolor tempora voluptas
    facere quam maiores. Voluptatem cum porro perspiciatis, obcaecati ratione repellat quasi voluptates. Quidem repudiandae, cum, necessitatibus autem laborum pariatur illum, omnis tempore doloribus nesciunt consequuntur temporibus nisi nostrum, voluptate
    eveniet deserunt repellendus? Ullam dicta ea tempore in nostrum natus, ipsam facilis, quidem cupiditate veritatis dolorum, sequi commodi illo rer
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="leftmenu_wrapper">
      <div class="leftmenu">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem expedita nisi, vero laborum nobis deleniti itaque ipsum eum non numquam enim est facere similique iure nostrum, dolorum totam dignissimos minima a. Officia delectus incidunt ea molestiae itaque
        molestias pariatur dolor quam eligendi quis rem, nihil magnam a, fugit deleniti id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem expedita nisi, vero laborum nobis deleniti itaque ipsum eum non numquam enim est facere similique
        iure nostrum, dolorum totam dignissimos minima a. Officia delectus incidunt ea molestiae itaque molestias pariatur dolor quam eligendi quis rem, nihil magnam a, fugit deleniti id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem expedita
        nisi, vero laborum nobis deleniti itaque ipsum eum non numquam enim est facere similique iure nostrum, dolorum totam dignissimos minima a. Officia delectus incidunt ea molestiae itaque molestias pariatur dolor quam eligendi quis rem, nihil magnam
        a, fugit deleniti id.
        iure nostrum, dolorum totam dignissimos minima a. Officia delectus incidunt ea molestiae itaque molestias pariatur dolor quam eligendi quis rem, nihil magnam a, fugit deleniti id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem expedita
        nisi, vero laborum nobis deleniti itaque ipsum eum non numquam enim est facere similique iure nostrum, dolorum totam dignissimos minima a. Officia delectus incidunt ea molestiae itaque molestias pariatur dolor quam eligendi quis rem, nihil magnam
        a, fugit deleniti id.
      </div>
      <div class="button">Open leftmenu</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Как я понял вам нужно подобное решение?

Это полностью реализуется на чистом css, `media` запросом. Js тут не нужен.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Теперь работает как надо

Comment: Если надо прикрутить разворачивание/сворачивание - дайте знать. Сделаю.

Comment: почему content прокручивать нельзя?

Comment: По моему в вопросе ясно сказано , что если открыто левое меню - контент не прокручивался.

Comment: Благодарен за данный способ, можете прокомментировать моё решение?

Comment: Не советую вам использовать js для применение стилей к селекторам. Все спокойно делается в css. Щас доделаю свое решение.

Comment: @kiLLro имелось в виду при открытии меню и меню можно закрыть, а у вас закрыть нельзя.

Comment: @kiLLro Так же у меня возникает такая проблема, на меньшем разрешении размера блока не хватает, увеличивая его размер он становится больше и на других разрешениях (Пример): http://imgur.com/a/9yUIi

Comment: Обновил код. Меню раскроется автоматически при расширении >=500px. Не знаю зачем я это сделал, но если что это можно удалить.

Comment: @user234223 используйте мое решение, реализуйте все через css.

Comment: @kiLLro покажите пожалуйста на моём примере, в css анимации я так же не силён, у себя я нашёл такой минус, когда из любого места клацаешь на кнопку что активирует меню (которое к слову fixed), сайт автоматически скроллится наверх